# How to read data from the Telegram database?

Tags: database, sqlite, telegram

I have installed Telegram on MacOS.

"~/Library/Group Containers/XXXXXXXX.en.keepcoder.Telegram/" this folder contains the db_sqlite, db_sqlite-wal files. I can't open them via SQLiteBrowser, when i try to do this i get this message:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DieBy.png)

How to read data from these files?

Thanks.